# tomcat run shell script and return the process to system

Tags: java, linux, shell, tomcat, glassfish

I have some scripts they have their own jobs and have to keep running with endless loop. I managed to start shell scripts within java servlet. And Servlet runs on Tomcat. However when I kill the server(it is for testing), all the running shell scripts died, no process can be grepped anymore.

Plus, because of this, I have to changed my server to Glassfish. It turned out, even when I kill the Glassfish , the process started by application running inside Glassfish still alive!!! This is confusing, because I thought they should be the same result. And tomcat is preferred in terms of its wide usage and faster managing console.

Does any one knows how to return the started process to the shell in tomcat. I don't know where the problem is .
My code to start the script is :

```
ProcessBuilder pb= new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "scriptDir/" + "xx.sh");
pb.start ;
```

Usually I can get the PID immediately form the terminal. Once tomcat is killed arll of them also disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the following test:

**case 1:**

1. start the app on tomcat
2. start all the scirpts
3. grep to be sure all process did start
4. kill tomcat and grep again

**result: all process die**

**case 2:**

1. start the app on glassfish
2. start all the scirpts
3. grep to be sure all process do start
4. kill glassfish and grep again

**result: all process keep alive**

**case3:**

1. start the app on tomcat
2. start the app on glassfish (abother port)
3. use app on tomcat to start all the scripts
4. grep to be sure

**3-1**

5. kill tomcat
6. grep again

**result: all process keep alive**

7. then  kill glassfish

**result: all process still alive**

**3-2**

5. kill glassfish
6. grep again

**result: all process keep alive**

7. kill tomcat

**result: all process die**

So I think in my case glassfish is the only choice. May be tomcat and glassfish has a different machanism during the termination. Tomcat seems kills all the hierarchical child processes while glassfish ignore them.